# TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm practicing with flask case from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sqlalchemy.htm. 
I tried to run the codes and check on http://localshot:5000. They were working fine at the first 3 steps.
When I tried to fill the contents on http://localhost:5000/new and click the "submit" button on last step, the error occurred.
I'm using python2.7 with PyCharm in Mac. Thx.

The codes are below:

app.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///students.sqlite3'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "random string"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class students(db.Model):

    id = db.Column('student_id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    city = db.Column(db.String(50))
    addr = db.Column(db.String(200))
    pin = db.Column(db.String(10))


def __init__(self, name, city, addr, pin):
    self.name = name
    self.city = city
    self.addr = addr
    self.pin = pin

#db.create_all()

# filter to the retrieved record set by using the filter attribute.
# For instance, in order to retrieve records with city = ’Hyderabad’
# in students table

# Students.query.filter_by(city = 'Hyderabad').all()


@app.route('/')
def show_all():
    return render_template('show_all.html', students = students.query.all())


@app.route('/new', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def new():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.form['name'] or not request.form['city'] or not request.form['addr']:
            flash('Please enter all the fields', 'error')
        else:
            student = students(request.form['name'], request.form['city'],
                               request.form['addr'], request.form['pin'])

            db.session.add(student)
            db.session.commit()

            flash('Record was successfully added')
            return redirect(url_for('show_all'))
    return render_template('new.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug = True)
```

new.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>

      <h3>Students - Flask SQLAlchemy example</h3>
      <hr/>

      {%- for category, message in get_flashed_messages(with_categories = true) %}
         <div class = "alert alert-danger">
            {{ message }}
         </div>
      {%- endfor %}

      <form action = "{{ request.path }}" method = "post">
         <label for = "name">Name</label><br>
         <input type = "text" name = "name" placeholder = "Name" /><br>
         <label for = "email">City</label><br>
         <input type = "text" name = "city" placeholder = "city" /><br>
         <label for = "addr">addr</label><br>
         <textarea name = "addr" placeholder = "addr"></textarea><br>
         <label for = "PIN">PINCODE</label><br>
         <input type = "text" name = "pin" placeholder = "pin" /><br>
         <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" />
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

show_all.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
   <head></head>
   <body>

      <h3>
         <a href = "{{ url_for('show_all') }}">Comments - Flask
            SQLAlchemy example</a>
      </h3>

      <hr/>
      {%- for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
         {{ message }}
      {%- endfor %}

      <h3>Students (<a href = "{{ url_for('new') }}">Add Student
         </a>)</h3>

      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>City</th>
               <th>Address</th>
               <th>Pin</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>

         <tbody>
            {% for student in students %}
               <tr>
                  <td>{{ student.name }}</td>
                  <td>{{ student.city }}</td>
                  <td>{{ student.addr }}</td>
                  <td>{{ student.pin }}</td>
               </tr>
            {% endfor %}
         </tbody>
      </table>

   </body>
</html>
```

Here are the details of error:

TypeError
TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/Applications/anaconda3/envs/SimpleFlaskExample1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Applications/anaconda3/envs/SimpleFlaskExample1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/Applications/anaconda3/envs/SimpleFlaskExample1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Applications/anaconda3/envs/SimpleFlaskExample1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Applications/anaconda3/envs/SimpleFlaskExample1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Applications/anaconda3/envs/SimpleFlaskExample1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Applications/anaconda3/envs/SimpleFlaskExample1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Applications/anaconda3/envs/SimpleFlaskExample1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/chenneyhuang/PycharmProjects/SimpleFlaskExample1/app.py", line 50, in new
request.form['addr'], request.form['pin'])
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)
```

Comment: In python, indentation matters. `def __init__(self, name, city, addr, pin):` needs to be under the class definition. As stands, your class only has the default `__init__`.

Comment: Haven't heard back from you. Let us know whether my response has been helpful.

Comment: Hi tdelaney. sorry for the delayed. I was misleading by the error message. I think you are right. I'm still working outside now. I will try once I get home and let you know. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python uses indentation to mark the scope of a block of code. Since your `__init__` is not indented, python ended the compilation of the class and compiled a module level function called `__init__`. That class already had an init that takes no additional parameters and since you didn't override it, that's the one you got.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution # I followed the same way you did from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sqlalchemy.htm
but I found the solution here its

```
from flask import Flask, request, flash, url_for, redirect, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///students.sqlite3'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "random string"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class students(db.Model):
   id = db.Column('student_id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(100))
   city = db.Column(db.String(50))
   addr = db.Column(db.String(200))
   pin = db.Column(db.String(10))





#bro you don't have to pass more than 1 argument
def __init__(self):
    self.name = name
    self.city = city
    self.addr = addr
    self.pin = pin







@app.route('/')
def show_all():
   return render_template('show_all.html', students = students.query.all() )

@app.route('/new', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def new():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        student=students()
        if not request.form['name'] or not request.form['city'] or not request.form['addr']:
            flash('Please enter all the fields', 'error')
        else:
            student.name = request.form['name']
            student.city = request.form['city']
            student.addr = request.form['addr']
            student.pin  = request.form['pin']

            db.session.add(student)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Record was successfully added')
            return redirect(url_for('show_all'))
    return render_template('new.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   db.create_all()
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: for the above code I posted it worked for me perfectly